# Inconveniente a filtrar data set :error de sintaxis falta el operando antes del operador en vb.net mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola buenos dias tengo un DataGridView ya enlazado a un dataset que trae unos campos de una tabla
la idea era filtrar y mostrarlos en base a una variable a que ya esta cargada el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    Private Sub familia_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim A As String
        A = Form1.DNIPP
        Dim m_Where As String = ""
        Dim m_Patron As String = "where"
        m_Where = (m_Patron + " " + "DNIAGENTE" + " " + A)
        MsgBox(m_Where)
        Me.DataTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CARGADATOSFAMILIA2.DataTable)
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = Me.CARGADATOSFAMILIA2.DataTable.Clone()
        Dim rows() As DataRow = CARGADATOSFAMILIA2.DataTable.Select(m_Where)
        For Each row As DataRow In rows
            dt1.ImportRow(row)
        Next
        DATOSCARGADOSFAMILIA.DataSource = dt1
        For Each row As DataRow In rows
            dt1.ImportRow(row)
        Next
        DATOSCARGADOSFAMILIA.DataSource = dt1

    End Sub
```

la idea es filtrar por la columna dniagente (campo double) con el valor de la variable A
agradecieria me sepan orientar

Comment: Creo que lo que faltaría invocar el metodo `.Refresh()` del datagridview despues de reasignar su datasource. Algo como `DATOSCARGADOSFAMILIA.Refresh()` despues del último `DATOSCARGADOSFAMILIA.DataSource = dt1`